# How to move a template from one xen nfs storage repository to another?

Tags: xen

I have a bunch of templates on an NFS XCP 1.6 storage repository using thin provisioning for some of my VMs.  I want to move the template's disks to a different NFS storage repository.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this using XenCenter, and I'm not having much luck finding the right combination of xe command line options.

Any and all help is appreciated.  Thanks!